# JqueryUI datepicker can be acessed but not used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, datepicker, html-helper

Im having some trouble installing JqueryUi to my mvc 5 application. I must have done something right because I can create this:

```
<div>
<label for="date">Select a date:</label> @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("date")
</div>
```

I´ve been following this guide:
http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/GettingStarted

All i get is an empty field...When I click it, Im supposed to get a datepicker..This is my _Layout, I try to render the jquery at the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/touchTouch.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/kwicks-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



</head>
<body>
    @*<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>*@
    <header>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar_">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h1 class="brand brand_"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img alt="" src="~/Content/img/ae.png"> </a></h1>
                            <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-navbar_" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse_">Menu <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
                            <div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse_  collapse">
                                <ul class="nav sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Hem</a></li>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Folio", "Home")">Foton</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        @RenderBody()

    <!--============================== footer =================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul class="list-social pull-right">
                <li><a class="icon-1" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-2" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-3" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-4" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </footer>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.preloader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">if ($(window).width() > 1024) { document.write("<" + "script src='js/jquery.preloader.js'></" + "script>"); }    </script>


    <script>
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        $x = $(window).width();
        if ($x > 1024) {
            jQuery("#content .row").preloader();
        }

        jQuery('.magnifier').touchTouch();
        jQuery('.spinner').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, 'easeOutCubic', function () { jQuery(this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });



    </script>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure to add required js files...

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand how to do that, would you mind showing?

Comment: Oh, the files got added automatically when i installed jqueryUi with nuget.

Comment: is there is any errors in console??

Comment: I got this error regarding jqueryUi:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: then required javascript jquery files are not added in ur viewpage...Nuget will add files automatically in bundleconfig but u have to include required js files in ur view implicitely as shown in tutorial which u have referred.

Comment: Ok, is that not what I have done at the bottom of my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` will just try to render a bundle called `~/bundles/jqueryui`, defined in your `\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` **but will render it wherever you tell it to**.

It will render at the end of the body element, but it is used earlier so will fail.

Simply put your scripts higher up the page before they are used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/touchTouch.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/kwicks-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



</head>
<body>
    @*<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>*@
    <header>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar_">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h1 class="brand brand_"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img alt="" src="~/Content/img/ae.png"> </a></h1>
                            <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-navbar_" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse_">Menu <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
                            <div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse_  collapse">
                                <ul class="nav sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Hem</a></li>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Folio", "Home")">Foton</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        @RenderBody()

    <!--============================== footer =================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <ul class="list-social pull-right">
                <li><a class="icon-1" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-2" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-3" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-4" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </footer>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.preloader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">if ($(window).width() > 1024) { document.write("<" + "script src='js/jquery.preloader.js'></" + "script>"); }    </script>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    // Call this and any other scripts after including the scripts
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script>
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        $x = $(window).width();
        if ($x > 1024) {
            jQuery("#content .row").preloader();
        }

        jQuery('.magnifier').touchTouch();
        jQuery('.spinner').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, 'easeOutCubic', function () { jQuery(this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im sorry friend, must have missed your answer. 
I always have trouble with my Jquerys and i´ll bookmark this answer for later reference. Thanks you!